# redux form Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, material-ui

- In my stepper code Iam trying to include the radio button.
- When I include the radio button I am getting the below error.
- I looked into this example https://redux-form.com/6.0.0-alpha.6/examples/simple/ and then imeplemented
- but still I am faccing errors.
- Can you tell me how to fix it, so that in future I will fix it myself.
- Providing my sandbox and code snippet below.

https://codesandbox.io/s/0prxxxvy0n

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
>   or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You
>   likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in,
>   or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

```
const AsyncValidationForm = props => {
  console.log("AsyncValidationForm ---->");

  const { handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting } = props;
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <Field
        name="username"
        type="text"
        component={renderField}
        label="Username"
      />
      <Field
        name="password"
        type="password"
        component={renderField}
        label="Password"
      />
      <Field name="sex" type="radio" value="male" />

      <div>
        <button type="submit" disabled={submitting}>
          Sign Up
        </button>
        <button type="button" disabled={pristine || submitting} onClick={reset}>
          Clear Values
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};
```

Comment: what is renderField

Comment: It looks like you're not passing the proper string to the Provider store. See the docs for an example https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react#passing-the-store

Comment: @SterlingArcher hey I looked at the documentation link,  do I need to add Provider. Its so confusing can you update in my sandbox

Comment: @nossr Please do not ask others to update your sandbox without at least doing the work of providing a [minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) sandbox that only contains the code necessary to reproduce the problem in the current question. Currently your sandbox contains large amounts of code unrelated to your question and that extra code has issues unrelated to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to add the renderField component to your radio field:

```
 <Field component={renderField} name="sex" type="radio" value="male" />
```

Why does it solve your issue?
What you are using here, is the Field component of redux-form. (See your import `import { Field, reduxForm } from "redux-form";`)
When you don't know how a component that you are integrating is working, there is always hope for a good documentation. In case of redux-form we are lucky: there actually is one that as well describes their Field component.

What we can get there is the following:

> 1. The name prop is required. It is a string path, in dot-and-bracket notation, corresponding to a value in the form values. It may be as simple as 'firstName' or as complicated as contact.billing.address[2].phones[1].areaCode.
> 2. The component prop is required. It may be a Component, a stateless function, or a factory, like those provided under React.DOM. See Usage section below. To learn about the props that will provided to whatever your component is, see the Props section below.
> 3. All other props will be passed along to the element generated by the component prop.

The second paragraph explains why your approach did not work out: the component prop is required. :)

Source: https://redux-form.com/6.0.0-alpha.6/docs/api/field.md/

Hope it helps.

Comment: hey thanks it worked, but can you tell me why we need to add renderField so that in future I will fix it myself