# placed the div between the StickyContainer component to make it sticky

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, material-ui

- I am trying to make a div sticky in react.
- so I included the package react-sticky.
- and placed the div between the StickyContainer component.
- I dont see any errors but still its not working.
- Can you tell me how to fix it, so that in future I will fix it myself.
- Providing my sandbox and code snippet below.

https://codesandbox.io/s/0prxxxvy0n

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log("App---->");
    return (
      <StickyContainer>
        {/* Other elements can be in between `StickyContainer` and `Sticky`,
        but certain styles can break the positioning logic used. */}

        <div>
          I am sticky------------------------------------------------------->
        </div>

        <Sticky>
          {({
            style,

            // the following are also available but unused in this example
            isSticky,
            wasSticky,
            distanceFromTop,
            distanceFromBottom,
            calculatedHeight
          }) => <header style={style}>{}</header>}
        </Sticky>
        <SearchBar />
        <div>I am sticky</div>
        <WholeText />
        <UploadDocuments />
        <VerticalLinearStepper />
        {/* ... */}
      </StickyContainer>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I am sticky seems to work as long as it's inside <Sticky></Sticky> component.

Comment: @BorisPovolotsky can you tell me how your seeing the code and telling it as a call back `{({ style })`

Comment: @BorisPovolotsky this is not true, it requires the sticky content to be passed a style prop from the Sticky component and so needs to be inside a render callback.

Comment: @markmoxx so the return method inside the render method forms a callback?

Comment: @nossr Don't get too hung up on the word 'callback' - that's just what the sticky documentation calls it. They're more commonly referred to as [Render Props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html). Any chance you can mark my answer as accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the documentation says, you need to put your div within the render callback of the  component, i.e.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log("App---->");
    return (
      <StickyContainer>
        <Sticky>
          {({ style }) => <div style={style}>I am sticky</div>}
        </Sticky>
        <SearchBar />
        <div>I am sticky</div>
        <WholeText />
        <UploadDocuments />
        <VerticalLinearStepper />
        {/* ... */}
      </StickyContainer>
    );
  }
}
```

A "render callback" in this case just means that the child of the `<Sticky>` component needs to be a function that returns what should be rendered. This allows the parent to pass additional information to use in the rendering of the child via the arguments of the function. The syntax for specifying a function as a child is:

```
<Parent>{/*function goes here*/}</Parent>
```

In the example above, the function part is `({ style }) => <div style={style}>I am sticky</div>` which assumes the parameter that will be passed to the function will be an object with a `style` property and then the function returns a div element using that style.

If you look at the [react-sticky code](https://github.com/captivationsoftware/react-sticky/blob/master/src/Sticky.js) you'll find that in its `render` method it does the following:

```
  const element = React.cloneElement(
      this.props.children({
        isSticky: this.state.isSticky,
        wasSticky: this.state.wasSticky,
        distanceFromTop: this.state.distanceFromTop,
        distanceFromBottom: this.state.distanceFromBottom,
        calculatedHeight: this.state.calculatedHeight,
        style: this.state.style
      }),
      {
        ref: content => {
          this.content = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(content);
        }
      }
    );
```

When it calls `this.props.children(...)`, that executes the function you specified as a child and you can see that the last property on the object it passes to the function is the `style` property.

Comment: hey thanks its working...can you tell me why your calling as render callback, how your telling as callback if you explain that would be great since in interviews I can tell explain them with an example

Comment: Because the documentation told me to do that. Seriously though, [give it a read](https://github.com/captivationsoftware/react-sticky#overview--basic-example), specifically: "`react-sticky` works by calculating the position of a `<Sticky>` component relative to a `<StickyContainer>` component. If it would be outside the viewport, the styles required to affix it to the top of the screen are passed as an argument to a render callback, a function passed as a child."

Comment: can you tell me how your seeing the code and telling it as a call back `{({ style })`

Comment: To be honest it's the first time I've come across it 'in the wild'. Here's some further reading: https://reactpatterns.com/ (See the Render Props section) and also https://medium.com/@adamrackis/simplifying-life-with-react-render-callbacks-cb37d58e55

Comment: @nossr I've updated markmoxx's answer with a fuller explanation of the "render callback" aspect.

Comment: @RyanCogswell thanks man, explained it far better than I could

Comment: Hey since they are using props.children your putting inside the child element... thanks for your help...

Comment: Can you help me with this one too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54224438/redux-form-element-type-is-invalid-expected-a-string-for-built-in-components